# PDO fetchcolumn not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a web application in PHP, but for some reason does `$count` return nothing. I have tried to see if it echos an int but it does not.

Here is my code:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_name' = '$username' AND WHERE 'password' ='$password'");
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->fetchColumn();
    ;
    if($count==1){
       $_session['username'] =$username;
        $_session['logged_in'] =true;
  header('location: addfile.php');


    }else{
        echo "<p> gegevens kloppen niet</p>";
        echo "<p>$count</p>";
    }

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){

        $error = true;

    }
```

Comment: You are misusing single quotes (`'`). You should not have them around the column names or table name. Also, you can have only one `WHERE` clause. The syntax is `WHERE x AND y`, not `WHERE x AND WHERE y`. Turning on error reporting would have revealed these basic errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try `$count = $query->rowCount()`
I've had the same issue in the past and rowCount works where fetchColumn doesn't.
I'm not entirely sure on the query you have also.
You might have to change it to

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = $username and password = $password
```